# Remote JMS glassfish 3.x

Tags: java, glassfish, jms, jndi

I've created standalone remote client for embedded JMS that stands on glassfish3 server.

Client code :

```
    jndiContext = new InitialContext();
    queueConnectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) jndiContext.lookup("topekFactory");
    queue = (Topic) jndiContext.lookup("topek");
```

Client works fine only if its on the same machine. Every time I try to run it on the remote machine it hangs on second line.

I'm using -Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=10.10.10.2 to point glassfish server. 
Also tried to create InitialContext with properties :

```
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "10.10.10.2");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
```

But no positive results.

Any ideas, what am doing wrong? how to connect remote client with glassfish embedded jms ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the server bound to the 10.10.10.2 or 0.0.0.0 address? What OS r u running the server on?

Comment: Tried on windows and SLES11 (listenieng is 0.0.0.0). It is 100% times reproducable on diferrent machines/OS. Is there some configuration that limits remote connectons?

Comment: Can you access the 8080 port?

Comment: Without any problems on second machine is running other node of the cluster, all Firewall on boht machines is off. Funny think is that I can telnet on port 3700, so the problem is deeper

Comment: It's the first time you mention cluster in your post...that's why I gave you the answer I did. I will try to see if I can come up with something with clustering.

Comment: I'm configuring JMS on different instance, I mentioned about cluster because I already solved Firewall problems erlier while setting up cluster envorionment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access the 8080 port remotely?

Try to access a sample web application from a remote machine. e.g http://10.10.10.2/sample/. If you can't access it remotely and you can access it locally this means that glassfish maybe bound on localhost address.

Check your domain.xml and see the IP addresses the various network listeners bind on. If it's 0.0.0.0 this means a firewall is probably blocking incoming connections. If they are 127.0.0.1 then you have to change them to the network IP or any IP(0.0.0.0).

If everything is OK with your configuration and you still can't access it after a restart then disable any firewall entirely to see if everything works OK in that case.

Check [this](http://www.randombugs.com/java/glassfish/changeing-defaults-ports-jms-glassfish.html) out

in order to see which ports are required by default in case it's the firewall and add the required rules on your firewall to allow proper access

Now that you mentioned cluster. This might help:

[check this out](http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/glassfish-31-jms-cluster)

Comment: Firewalls are off and nhere is no 127.0.0.1 in domain config